# Updates to code on Xamarin iOS application are not applying at runtime/debug

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have an application which I am developing. Everything has been going smoothly, but suddenly my code no longer applies when I deploy. If I make a change and deploy the app to my iPhone, the app launches but my changes do not appear.

Furthermore, my breakpoints hollow, which I believe means that the code that is running differs from the code in Visual Studio.

[image]

I am running Visual Studio 2022 on Mac, deploying to my iphone hardware.

I have tried:

- Normal build and run
- Build -> Rebuild Solution

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: delete your app from the phone, kill VS, clear all bin/obj folders, then do a rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following steps:

1. Open the location of my iOS project (note that I also have Android projects and other libraries, but I only did this for the iOS location)
2. Delete the **bin** and **obj** folders
3. Build project, observe there are now errors due to references missing to classes which should come from nuget packages
4. Right-click on the Packages folder in the solution explorer and select **Restore**
5. Build and deploy the project

I'm not sure why my project got in this state, but this seems to solve it when it does happen.